# Doubts in accuracy assessment of binary classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, auc

I am doing a binary classification using the `sequential()` model of Keras. I have some doubts about its accuracy assessment.

I am calculating AUC-ROC for it. **For this, should I use the prediction probability or the prediction class?**

*Explanation:*

After training the `model`, I'm doing `model.predict()` to find prediction values for training and validation data (code below).

```
y_pred_train = model.predict(x_train_df).ravel()
y_pred_val = model.predict(x_val_df).ravel()

fpr_train, tpr_train, thresholds_roc_train = roc_curve(y_train_df, y_pred_train, pos_label=None)
fpr_val, tpr_val, thresholds_roc_val = roc_curve(y_val_df, y_pred_val, pos_label=None)

roc_auc_train = auc(fpr_train, tpr_train)
roc_auc_val = auc(fpr_val, tpr_val)

plt.figure()
lw = 2
plt.plot(fpr_train, tpr_train, color='darkgreen',lw=lw, label='ROC curve Training (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc_train)
plt.plot(fpr_val, tpr_val, color='darkorange',lw=lw, label='ROC curve Validation (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc_val)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=lw, linestyle='--',label='Base line')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic (ROC) Curve')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

This shows the plot as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LITu3.png). training and validation accuracies are 0.76 and 0.76.

model.predict() gives the probabilities not the actual predicted class, so I chnaged the first two line of the above code sample to give the class as;

```
y_pred_train = (model.predict(x_train_df).ravel() > 0.5).astype("int32")
y_pred_val = (model.predict(x_test_df).ravel() > 0.5).astype("int32")
```

So this now calculates the AUC-ROC from the class values (I guess). But the accuracy I am getting with this is very different and low. Training and validation accuracies are 0.66 and 0.46. ([plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ6fS.png)).

**What is the correct way between these two and why the difference in accuracies?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ROC is normally created by plotting sensitivity (TPR) vs specificity (FPR) when varying the class thresholding value from 0. to 1.0 eg:
See for instance here:
https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/roc-and-auc
Some pseudo code to get you started:

```
pred_proba = model.predict(x_train_df).ravel()

for thresh in np.arange (0, 1, 0.1):
    pred = np.where(pred_proba >thresh ,1,0)

    # assuming you have a truth array of 0,1 classifications
    #now you can assess sensitivy by calculating true positive, false positive,...
    tp= np.count_nonzero(truth & pred)
    # same for false positive, false negative,...
    # they you can evaluate your sensitivity (TPR) and specificity(FPR) for the current threshold
    tpr = (tp / (tp + fn)
    # same for fpr
    # now you can plot the tpr, fpr point for the current treshold value
```

Comment: Okay, you have implemented the calculation of tpr and fpr.  `roc_curve()` do the same I think. So we have to use the prediction probability, not the class value, right?

Comment: Yes the ROC is based on assigning different class class values from the same original prediction probability. Usually the objective is to identify a threshold (not 0.5 necessarly) that would satistisfy specific sensitivity and specificity objective. (Eg in medical diagnostic you might want to favor false positive over false negative) for a given intrinsic classifier performance. So you need to use the prediction probabilities